# Angular 2 : send event to child on tab change

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am using Angular material tabs and what I want to do is that **when I click on a tab, I send an event to the child of this tab**.

My HTML looks like this

```
<md-tab-group *ngIf="me">
  <md-tab label="Gallery" i18n-label="@@gallery">
    <app-gallery [user]="me"></app-gallery>
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Profile" i18n-label="@@profile">
    <app-profile [user]="me"></app-profile>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

The tabs already have the change event implemented. The problem is that I can handle the event on my main component, but not in my gallery component. Is there a way to transmit the event to the gallery component, without using a service just for that ?

Thnank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the child components(gallery in this case) methods from the parent by giving the child a selector in the template

```
<md-tab-group *ngIf="me">
  <md-tab label="Gallery" i18n-label="@@gallery">
    <app-gallery #galleryEl [user]="me"></app-gallery> //<--- add the html selector here
  </md-tab>
  <md-tab label="Profile" i18n-label="@@profile">
    <app-profile [user]="me"></app-profile>
  </md-tab>
</md-tab-group>
```

**Parent.ts:**

```
@ViewChild('galleryEl') galleryEl ;
```

and then you can use this field to call methods of this component.

```
this.galleryEl.someEventMethod(theEvent);
```

Comment: I just discovered that, didn't know, it's amazing ! Thank you for the answer !